# How to remove HTML element dynamically when others are been removed using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html code here:

```
  <div class="container">
    <section>
      <header class="date">May 2014</header>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, dolorem, laborum non illum voluptate vitae quibusdam impedit</article>
      <article>Repellendus, dolorem, laborum non illum voluptate vitae quibusdam impedit aperiam placeat minus ratione mollitia expedita tempore reprehenderit maxime.</article>
      <article>ratione mollitia expedita tempore reprehenderit maxime.</article>
      <a href="#">Remove Article</a>
    </section>

    <section>
      <header class="date">March 2014</header>
      <article>Repellendus, dolorem, laborum non illum voluptate vitae quibusdam impedit aperiam placeat minus ratione mollitia expedita tempore reprehenderit maxime unde quas beatae maiores.
      </article>
      <a href="#">Remove Article</a>
    </section>

    <section>
      <header class="date">April 2014</header>
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</article>
      <article>Repellendus, dolorem, laborum non illum voluptate vitae quibusdam impedit aperiam placeat minus ratione mollitia expedita tempore reprehenderit maxime unde quas beatae maiores.
      </article>
      <a href="#">Remove Article</a>
    </section>
  </div>
```

When I click on 'Remove Article" link i should remove one of the article above it. I've got that.

Now what i'm trying to accomplish here is, when I remove all articles 'one by one' that belongs to specific section  I need automaticly to have the header 'date' and the link 'Remove Article' to be removed completely.

I have tried different ways, but still I can see both header and link, but when I refresh page they are gone.

Comment: Post your JavaScript please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got you. Do you want to remove `article`s one by one then if there's no more remove the whole `section`? If so, this should work:

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $section = $(this).closest('section'),
      $articles = $section.find('article');

  $articles.last().remove();


  // $articles.length will not be one less just because we removed 
  // an item, so just checking for 1 here is the same as checking
  // if it's empty.

  if ($articles.length === 1) {
    $section.remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: yes, that's what I was looking for. Each time i click on 'Remove Article' it deletes one. When I delete last article it deletes the whole section which include Header and link. 
Before I asked the question, I had the part done, i was missing [ last().remove ]. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you tried binding this.parentElement.remove() to the a elements in your html? It will remove the entire section.

```
$('.container a').click(function(){
     this.parentNode.remove()
}
```

Comment: This would be better as a comment since it does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: note this currently is not supported in any version of IE

Comment: fine. i'll change it to node

Comment: Why? you are using jquery so use the parent() function!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('section a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    var articles = self.siblings('article');
    if (articles.length > 1) {
        articles.last().remove();
    }
    else {
        self.parent().remove();
    }
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PD94p/4/)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: removes each article until only one is left in a section, then removes last article and section. Thanks @Barmar for pointing out my error.

```
$('body').on('click', '.container a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var articleLength = $(this).closest('section').find('article').length;
    if (1 != articleLength) {
        $(this).closest('section').find('article:last').remove();
    } else {
        $(this).closest('section').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: This will remove the section even if there are still other articles in it. He only wants to remove the section when all articles have been removed.